# Make a custom score counter in unity with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a custom score counter in unity, currently I am using the below code to create the score counter.

```
`void OnGUI () {
         GUILayout.BeginArea ( new Rect( Screen.width/2-Screen.width / 8, 10, Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4 ) );
         GUILayout.Box ( score.ToString () );
         GUILayout.EndArea ();
     }`
```

What i am trying to achieve is like a a digital clock type counter, so there would be an image of the of the background then the number in the center of that background would change as score increased.  I would also like to implement a sort of flick down as if you turned a page in a notebook type effect when the score increased.

edit**
I know I can use guitexture and add different images to it as score changes, I am able to do this so if somebody could tell me how id add a animation like the page turn to it as the score changes that would be perfect also.

Any help with completing this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public GUITexture textureScore;
public Texture2D zero;
public Texture2D one;
public Texture2D two;
public Texture2D three;
public Texture2D four;
public Texture2D five;


void Update () {
    if(score == 0){
            textureScore.guiTexture.texture = zero;     
        }else if(score == 1){
            textureScore.guiTexture.texture = one;              
        }else if(score == 2){
            textureScore.guiTexture.texture = two;              
        }else if(score == 3){
            textureScore.guiTexture.texture = three;                
        }else if(score == 4){
            textureScore.guiTexture.texture = four;             
        }else if(score == 5){
            textureScore.guiTexture.texture = five;             
        }
}
```

not perfect but it works

Comment: Just an idea: I used to work with the native Unity GUI as well and then switched to NGUI when my menus got more complex. I am still happy with my decision.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a List<Texture2D> and then index that list with score..